# HMS Push Kit для Xamarin, не срабатывает параметр "foreground_show": false

Tags: android, xamarin, push-уведомления

Согласно документации от Huawei, чтобы пуш-уведомления с типом notification не выводились в области уведомлений, а передавались в обработчик OnMessageReceived, необходимо в теле сообщения установить параметр   "foreground_show": false, примерно так:

```
    {
    "message": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "message title",
            "body": "message body"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "foreground_show": false,
                "click_action": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "action": "com.huawei.codelabpush.intent.action.test"
                }
            }
        },
        "token": [
            "pushtoken1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Или я что-то упускаю, или в HMS Push Kit все-таки есть баг.
Сервис, реализующий функции из HmsMessageService, сделал, настройки в AndroidManifest прописал по их образцам. Токены приложением получаются, Data messages ловятся, по тапу на Notification messages, когда приложение в фоне, само приложение стартует, но при запущенном - перехватить не удается.

Кто-то еще натыкался на такое?